Android Studio Calculator App Turning Off
I'm using Android Studio to create a Calculator App with java.
If I press the "CE" or the "=" button twice it the app closed by itself.
I still can't understand why.
I tought that it could have something to do with the zahl1 and zahl2 value, but i don't know why and how.
here im listing the Logcat message:
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
Caused by: java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: begin 0, end -1, length 0

the methods that might be the cause are: onRemoveClick & onGleichClick
here the java code :
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
{
    // TextViews
    private TextView tvBerechnung;
    private TextView tvResultat;

    // Zahlen
    private Button num0;
    private Button num1;
    private Button num2;
    private Button num3;
    private Button num4;
    private Button num5;
    private Button num6;
    private Button num7;
    private Button num8;
    private Button num9;

    // Funktionen
    private Button back;
    private Button remove;
    private Button clear;
    private Button gleich;
    private Button punkt;

    // Operatoren
    private Button plus;
    private Button minus;
    private Button mal;
    private Button durch;

    private String zahl1 = "";
    private String zahl2 = "";
    private String operator = "";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        EdgeToEdge.enable(this);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // TextViews
        tvBerechnung = findViewById(R.id.tvBerechnung);
        tvResultat = findViewById(R.id.tvResultat);

        // Zahlen
        num0 = findViewById(R.id.btn0);
        num1 = findViewById(R.id.btn1);
        num2 = findViewById(R.id.btn2);
        num3 = findViewById(R.id.btn3);
        num4 = findViewById(R.id.btn4);
        num5 = findViewById(R.id.btn5);
        num6 = findViewById(R.id.btn6);
        num7 = findViewById(R.id.btn7);
        num8 = findViewById(R.id.btn8);
        num9 = findViewById(R.id.btn9);

        // Funktionen
        back = findViewById(R.id.btnBack);
        remove = findViewById(R.id.btnC);
        clear = findViewById(R.id.btnCE);
        gleich = findViewById(R.id.btnGleich);
        punkt = findViewById(R.id.btnPunkt);

        // Operatoren
        plus = findViewById(R.id.btnPlus);
        minus = findViewById(R.id.btnMinus);
        mal = findViewById(R.id.btnMal);
        durch = findViewById(R.id.btnDurch);

        // Click listener für die num buttons
        onNumClick(num0, "0");
        onNumClick(num1, "1");
        onNumClick(num2, "2");
        onNumClick(num3, "3");
        onNumClick(num4, "4");
        onNumClick(num5, "5");
        onNumClick(num6, "6");
        onNumClick(num7, "7");
        onNumClick(num8, "8");
        onNumClick(num9, "9");

        // Click listener für die Operatoren
        onOperatorClick(plus, "+");
        onOperatorClick(minus, "-");
        onOperatorClick(mal, "*");
        onOperatorClick(durch, "/");

        // tvBerechnung und tvResultat leeren
        tvBerechnung.setText("");
        tvResultat.setText("");
    }

    // Zahlen in tvBerechnung anzeigen
    public void onNumClick(Button button, String value)
    {
        button.setOnClickListener(v ->
        {
            // falls ein operator in tvBerechnung steht, denn tvBerechnung leeren und die Zahl hinzufügen
            if (!Objects.equals(operator, ""))
            {
                tvBerechnung.setText("");
                tvBerechnung.append(value);
                zahl2 = tvBerechnung.getText().toString();
            }
            else
            {
                tvBerechnung.append(value);
                zahl1 = tvBerechnung.getText().toString();
            }
        });
    }

    // wenn auf C geklickt wird tvBerechnung und tvResultat leeren
    public void onClearClick(View view)
    {
        tvBerechnung.setText("");
        tvResultat.setText("");

        zahl1 = "";
        zahl2 = "";
        operator = "";
    }

    // wenn auf CE geklickt wird eine Zahl von tvBerechnung löschen
    public void onRemoveClick(View view)
    {
        // holt String aus tvBerechnung
        String str = tvBerechnung.getText().toString();

        if (str == null)
        {
            return;
        }
        else
        {
            // löscht das letzte Zeichen, 0 ist das erste index, also length -> total index - 1
            str = str.substring(0, (str.length()) - 1);

            // neuen String
            tvBerechnung.setText(str);
        }
    }

    // damit nicht mehr als ein Punkt in tvBerechnung steht
    public void onPunktClick(View view)
    {
        String str = tvBerechnung.getText().toString();

        if (str.contains("."))
        {
            return;
        }
        else
        {
            tvBerechnung.append(".");
        }
    }

    // für den +/- Button, also entwerde + oder -
    public void onPlusMinusClick(View view)
    {
        String str = tvBerechnung.getText().toString();

        // von - zu + wechseln
        if (str.contains("-"))
        {
            // löscht das erste Zeichen
            str = str.substring(1);

            tvBerechnung.setText("");
            tvBerechnung.setText(str);
        }
        // zu - wechseln
        else
        {
            tvBerechnung.setText("-" + str);
        }

        // falls operator leer ist, dann ist es die erste Zahl
        if (operator.isEmpty())
        {
            zahl1 = tvBerechnung.getText().toString();
        }
        else
        {
            zahl2 = tvBerechnung.getText().toString();
        }
    }

    // für die Operatoren, also tvBerechnung leeren und den Operator hinzufügen
    public void onOperatorClick(Button button, String value)
    {
        button.setOnClickListener(v ->
        {
            tvBerechnung.setText("");
            tvBerechnung.append(value);
            operator = value;
        });
    }

    // Berechnung
    public void onGleichClick(View view)
    {
        float z1 = Float.parseFloat(zahl1);
        float z2 = Float.parseFloat(zahl2);

        switch (operator)
        {
            // Addition
            case "+":
                float summe = z1 + z2;
                tvResultat.setText(String.valueOf(summe));
                break;

            // Subtraktion
            case "-":
                float differenz = z1 - z2;
                tvResultat.setText(String.valueOf(differenz));
                break;

            // Multiplikation
            case "*":
                float produkt = z1 * z2;
                tvResultat.setText(String.valueOf(produkt));
                break;

            // Division
            case "/":
                float quotient = z1 / z2;
                tvResultat.setText(String.valueOf(quotient));
                break;
        }

    }


}

I've tried debuggin, but it takes too long to load, and i also tried going trough the code again line by line but still couldn't figure out the cause.
also this is the xml code:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvBerechnung"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="18dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="17dp"
        android:text="Berechnung"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvResultat"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="18dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="56dp"
        android:text="Resultat"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnBack"
        style="@style/BtnAzo"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="9dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="2dp"
        android:text="BACK"
        app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@+id/btnCE"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/btnCE"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnCE"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
        android:text="CE"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/btnC"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/btnBack"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tvResultat"
        android:onClick="onRemoveClick"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnC"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="3dp"
        android:text="C"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/btnPlusMinus"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/btnCE"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/btnCE"
        android:onClick="onClearClick"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnPlusMinus"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="+/-"
        app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@+id/btnC"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/btnC"
        android:onClick="onPlusMinusClick"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn7"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="9dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="2dp"
        android:text="7"
        app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@+id/btn8"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/btn8"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn8"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="9dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
        android:text="8"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/btn9"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/btn7"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/btnCE" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn9"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="9dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="3dp"
        android:text="9"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/btnMal"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/btn8"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/btnC" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnMal"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="*"
        app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@+id/btn9"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/btn9" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="1dp"
        android:text="4"
        app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@+id/btn5"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/btn5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn5"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
        android:text="5"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/btn6"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/btn4"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/btn8" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn6"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="3dp"
        android:text="6"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/btnMinus"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/btn5"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/btn9" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnMinus"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="-"
        app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@+id/btn6"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/btn6" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="1dp"
        android:text="1"
        app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@+id/btn2"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/btn2"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
        android:text="2"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/btn3"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/btn1"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/btn5" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="3dp"
        android:text="3"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/btnPlus"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/btn2"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/btn6" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnPlus"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="+"
        app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@+id/btn3"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/btn3" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn0"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="1dp"
        android:text="0"
        app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@+id/btnPunkt"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/btnPunkt"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnPunkt"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="9dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
        android:text="."
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/btnDurch"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/btn0"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/btn2"
        android:onClick="onPunktClick"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnDurch"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="9dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="3dp"
        android:text="/"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/btnGleich"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/btnPunkt"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/btn3" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnGleich"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="="
        app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@+id/btnDurch"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/btnDurch"
        android:onClick="onGleichClick"/>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>


Is there any information to be found in the Logcat after the application closes unexpectedly?

yeah it shows:
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
Caused by: java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: begin 0, end -1, length 0

That is key information and I suggest that you [edit] your original post and include the Logcat error message, the full message, indicate which line of code is involved (it should tell you this) and then do some debugging regarding that line.

You're not taking into account empty Strings. In onRemoveClick(...) change if (str == null) to if (str == null || str.trim().isEmpty()) so that the method will return immediately if no data is held by the String.

Thanks, it helped with the "CE" button but the "=" button still causes issues. In the Logcat it shows "Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: empty String"

Or better, like this answer

I was able to fix it, the problem was that it tried to parse an empty string ("") as a number, so i modified the code to ensure that zahl1 and zahl2 are not empty before attempting to parse them as floats. anyways thank for the quick support. :)

More importantly, find some tutorials on Android debugging since the bigger and more robust fix is to learn to use the Logcat to identify and fix these issues yourself.
